show context around point
Given the following org file, suppose I take the following actions:
* One
** two
xxx


move point to "xxx"
(point-to-register ?a)
move point to "One"
org-cycle ;; fold headings
(jump-to-register ?a)

Due to the outline folding, point moves to a location in the file that is not visible.
Is there a command that expands the entry around point? Some of the obvious candidates (eg. org-fold-reveal) don't have the desired effect.
NB: Jump to location in org-mode while properly unfolding headings seems to be asking the same question, without any satisfactory answers.

Lack of an accepted answer isn't a reason to post a duplicate question.
